# Misunderstand singly Linked List

Tags: data-structures, singly-linked-list

I have misunderstood the implementation of a singly linked list, if the length in a linked list is 0, let the head and tail equal the new node there is no problem with me.

But when I try to add a new node I mutate it with `this.tail.next = newNode` and this.tail equal newNode.

The problem how this.head take new node?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> how `this.head` take new node?

When the second node is added, `this.head` references the first node, and that is what it still should reference after the second node has been added. The addition happens by *mutating* the `next` member of the first node, so that it references the second node.

It may help to visualse this. After the first node has been inserted (let's say with value 1), we have this state with the instance of the `SinglyLinkedList` class and the first instance of the `Node` class:

```
 this
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ tail: ─────────┐
│ head: ───────┐ │
│ length: 1  │ │ │
└────────────┘ │ │
               ▼ ▼
         ┌────────────┐
         │ value: 1   │
         │ next: null │
         └────────────┘
```

Now let's look at what happens when the second node (with value 2) is added. First `newNode` is assigned a new instance of `Node` that has received a value:

```
 this
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ tail: ─────────┐
│ head: ───────┐ │
│ length: 1  │ │ │
└────────────┘ │ │
               ▼ ▼
         ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
         │ value: 1   │   │ value: 2   │
         │ next: null │   │ next: null │
         └────────────┘   └────────────┘
                                ↑
                             newNode
```

Then the link is established with `this.tail.next = newNode`:

```
 this
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ tail: ─────────┐
│ head: ───────┐ │
│ length: 1  │ │ │
└────────────┘ │ │
               ▼ ▼
         ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
         │ value: 1   │   │ value: 2   │
         │ next: ────────│ next: null │
         └────────────┘   └────────────┘
                                ↑
                             newNode
```

Note how this builds a *chain* of references, such that now not only `this.tail.next === newNode`, but also `this.head.next === newNode`!

Just to finish up the scenario of insertion, we execute `this.tail = newNode` and `this.length++` which results in this state:

```
 this
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ tail: ────────────────────────┐
│ head: ───────┐                │
│ length: 2  │ │                │
└────────────┘ │                │
               ▼                ▼
         ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
         │ value: 1   │   │ value: 2   │
         │ next: ────────│ next: null │
         └────────────┘   └────────────┘
                                ↑
                             newNode
```

I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Yes, It's become clearer. Thank you